# Custom Angular Schematics: how to modify files and create files in different locations/folders

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I've been creating a custom Angular Schematics following this article: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4

Now I'm trying to find out how to modify some files (for example app-routing.module.ts, to add the route of the component created via my custom schematics). Is it possible? Could anyone provide an example?

I also would like to create files in different locations/folders at the same time.

This is the current structure of my custom schematics:

> - src
>
>   - table
>
>     - files
>
>       - __name@dasherize __-table
>
>         - __name@dasherize __-table-routing.module.ts
>         - __name@dasherize __-table.component.html
>         - __name@dasherize __-table.component.scss
>         - ...
>       - index.ts
>       - schema.d.ts
>       - schema.json
>   - collection.json
> - ...

And this is my current code:

**index.ts**

```
import { strings } from '@angular-devkit/core';
import {
    apply, mergeWith, move, Rule, SchematicContext, SchematicsException, template, Tree, url
} from '@angular-devkit/schematics';
import { parseName } from '@schematics/angular/utility/parse-name';
import { buildDefaultPath } from '@schematics/angular/utility/project';

import { Schema } from './schema';

export function tabla(_options: Schema): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    const workspaceConfigBuffer = tree.read('angular.json');

    if (!workspaceConfigBuffer) {
      throw new SchematicsException('Not an Angular CLI workspace');
    }

    const workspaceConfig = JSON.parse(workspaceConfigBuffer.toString());
    const projectName = _options.project || workspaceConfig.defaultProject;
    const project = workspaceConfig.projects[projectName];
    const defaultProjectPath = buildDefaultPath(project);
    const parsedPath = parseName(defaultProjectPath, _options.name);
    const { name, path } = parsedPath;
    const sourceTemplate = url('./files');

    const sourceParametrizedTemplate = apply(sourceTemplate, [
      template({
        ..._options,
        ...strings,
        name
      }),
      move(path)
    ]);

    return mergeWith(sourceParametrizedTemplate)(tree, _context);
  };
}
```

**schema.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
    "id": "SchematicsTable",
    "title": "Options Table Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "description": "Creates a page with a table",
    "properties": {
        "project": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Generates in a specific project"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Component's name",
            "$default": {
                "$source": "argv",
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name"
    ]
}
```

**schema.d.ts**

```
export interface Schema {
    project?: string;
    name: string;
}
```

**collection.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "table": {
      "description": "Page with a table",
      "factory": "./table/index#table",
      "schema": "./table/schema.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I execute "ng g my_package_name:table --name=example" in an Angular CLI workspace a folder "example-table" is created inside "src/app" with the following files inside it:

> - example-table-routing.module.ts
> - example-table.component.html
> - example-table.component.scss
> - ...

This alreay works fine, but what I would like is that at the same time this folder and files are created, the "app-routing.module.ts" file is modified adding the route of the example-table page and also creates a folder with some files in the folder "src/app/services".

Comment: Did you find some answers ?